# EXTJS--multiple btns with same handler. How to add cls when btn is clicked then remove when another btn is clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have multiple buttons that share the same handler. When a btn is clicked I change the background color by using addCls(). When another btn is clicked, I want to removeCls() from previous btn and addCls() to new btn.

snippet of code

//handler for multiple btns

```
handleWhatever: function (btn_){
  btn_.addCls("btncss");
  //do stuff
}
```

the question is.. at what point/where do I call removeCls()????

thanks!

just checked the docs ard there isnt a button "beforeclick" event either what the heckkkkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one simple way to do this is to select the buttons that has the class, call `.removeCls('btncss')` on it, and then add the css to the current button.

```
handleWhatever: function (btn_){

    // Get all elements with class 'btncss'
    // Alternatively use the btn_ reference and call ComponentQuery functions to 
    // reference your other buttons.
    var buttons = Ext.select('.btncss');

    if(buttons)
        buttons.removeCls('btncss');

    btn_.addCls("btncss");

    // do stuff
}
```

Another way would be to store a reference to the button that was clicked and then next time the handler function is called, simply call removeCls() on that reference